# How to make bash wait for a python script to finish running before another action

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have recently been developing a bash script to automatically run another python script I developed with selenium 10 times concurrently. I would usually use multiprocess inside of python but selenium has caused me some pain in concurrently running browsers.

In my bash script I have written a simple loop like below:

```
rangeEnd=$((10000/1000))
for num in $(seq 1 $rangeEnd)
do
  python3 myscript.py $num & disown;
wait
done
python3 nextscript.py
echo All done
```

What has perplexed me is that instead of running `myscript.py` 10 times and then after those scripts complete having `nextscript.py` execute, it seems to just execute the command `myscript.py` 10 times then immediately exit the loop and run the last script `nextscript.py`.

What I am hoping to figure out is, how I would make sure the bash script does not execute the final `nextscript.py` until all ten instances of `myscript.py` are complete.

For what it is worth, `myscript.py` should take somewhere in the order of 10 hours to complete running.

Sorry if this has been answered before, I am new to bash scripting and had some difficulty finding answers.

Comment: Don't `disown` stuff you don't want to `disown`.